# Determine if code is called from within the same assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, internal

I would like to lock down classes within my assembly to stop them being called from other classes within the same assembly.  So in other words, no sideways calls within the assembly.

I was going to write some validation in the class calls to make sure they are not called from within the same assembly.  How can I determine this using reflection?

So its the following scenario:

```
Assembly1
----------
Class 1A

Assembly2
----------
Class 2A
Class 2B
```

So class 2A cannot call class 2B.  But Class 1A can call Class 2A or Class 2B.

Comment: Isn't that what the keyword `internal` is for?

Comment: That sounds exactly backwards to most requirements. Is `Class2A` allowed to call `Class1A`, which in turn calls `Class2B`?

Comment: @juergend - No. It allows you to access classes within the same assembly, not across assemblies. It also doesn't _restrict_ access within the assembly.

Comment: @juergend - unless the OP has seriously mistyped several times, they seem to be seeking `anti-internal`...

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking about is not possible with the existing [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

You cannot make a class public to other assemblies but internally private.

If you split out your `Class2B` to a different assembly and make it [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx), you can also [set the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to `Assembly1`.

What this will achieve is that `Class2A` can't access it, but `Class1A` can.

---

You can do some runtime checks using reflection as well - as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414636/1583) by Christian.K details.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put them in the same assembly in the first place?

Rather put 2B and 2A in there own assemblies, marking the classes as `internal`. The provide the assembly-level attribute `InternalsVisibleTo` to allow "Assembly1" to access the internals of "Assembly2B" and "Assembly2A" respectively.

Using reflection, you would still be able to circumvent this.

Using such a mechanism (or any other one, handcrafted "caller checking", whatever) for security purposes is not advisable anyway. If you want to do it for "architectural" purposes, you could go with what was suggested above and possible use tools like [NDepend](http://ndepend.com/) or a custom FxCop/CodeAnalysis rule. You could validate that your rules are not broken during build time.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() == Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
{
    // Throw some exception
}
```

Seems a pretty weird thing to do though...